# Reuse lexer object in antlr4 python target

Tags: python, antlr, antlr4

I have a simple antlr4 lexer, the following script works,

```
    lexer  = MyLexer(InputStream(argv[1]))
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = MyParser(stream)
    tree   = parser.query()

    v = MyVisitor()
    v.visit(tree)
```

But I'm wondering if I can reuse the `MyLexer` class object?

If so, how can I re-set the input string?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by setting an input stream in the lexer (could even be the same as before) via `lexer.setInputStream()`. Then also re-set the lexer in the parser (can also be the same) via `parser.setTokenSource()`. Finally call `stream.reset()` and `parser.reset()` if you re-use them too.

FYI: if you even want to re-use the input stream you can call `input.load(text)` on it to load the new input.